# Asp.net core Razor Page - JQ data table not load data

Tags: asp.net-core, datatables

I have an Asp.net core project with Razor Page ,I try to implement a JQ data table but the data not load. 
Here is the Javascript code:

```
  $('#dataList').DataTable({

        // "iDisplayLength": 100,
        // "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            async: true,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '/CoursesDP/?handler=Data',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            data: function (d) {
                // note: d is created by datatable, the structure of d is the same with DataTableParameters model above
                //  console.log(JSON.stringify(d));
                return JSON.stringify(d);
            },
            success: function (r) {
                console.log(r);
            }

        },




        })
```

I write the data is coming to console:
{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":11,"recordsFiltered":11,"data":[["oooo"],["ccc"],["aaa"],["pppp"],["pppp"],["yyy"],["12"],["pppp"],["pppp"],["pppp"],["fff"]]}

This is the html code:

```
<table id="dataList" class="display" style="width:100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CourseDP[0].CourseName)
        </th>


    </tr>
</thead>
```

but the data not load to the data table .
What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The following is a working sample using DataTables with testing data, you can refer to it.

CoursesDP.cshtml:

```
@page
@model ModelValidation_MVC_.Pages.CourseDB.CoursesDPModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CoursesDP";
}

<h1>CourseDP</h1>

<div>
    <table id="dataList" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr class="table-info">
                <th>id</th>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>age</th>
                <th>phone</th>
                <th>email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        </table>
</div>
@section scripts{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $('#dataList').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            ajax: {
                type: "POST",
                url: '/CourseDB/CoursesDP/?handler=Data',
            },
            columns: [
                { data: 'id' },
                { data: 'name' },
                { data: 'age' },
                { data: 'phone' },
                { data: 'email' }
            ]
        })        
    </script>
}
```

CoursesDP.cshtml.cs:

```
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
public class CoursesDPModel : PageModel
{
    public static List<TestDT> testDTs = new List<TestDT> { new TestDT {id=1, name = "TestDT1", age = 1, phone = "1", email = "TestDT1@.com" },
        new TestDT {id=2, name = "TestDT2", age = 2, phone = "2", email = "TestDT2@.com" }, new TestDT {id=3, name = "TestDT3", age = 3, phone = "3", email = "TestDT3@.com" } ,
        new TestDT {id=4, name = "TestDT4", age = 4, phone = "4", email = "TestDT4@.com" }, new TestDT {id=5, name = "TestDT5", age = 5, phone = "5", email = "TestDT5@.com" } ,
        new TestDT {id=6, name = "TestDT6", age = 6, phone = "6", email = "TestDT6@.com" },new TestDT {id=7, name = "TestDT7", age = 7, phone = "7", email = "TestDT7@.com" },};
    public static List<TestId> testIds = new List<TestId> { new TestId { id = 1 }, new TestId { id = 2 } };
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        return Page();
    }

    public JsonResult OnPostData()
    {

        Postdata postdata = new Postdata { draw = 1, recordsTotal =7, recordsFiltered = 7, data = testDTs };

        return new JsonResult(postdata);
    }
}
```

result:
[image]